# How To Implement A Swipable Tab Host In Android

Tags: android, tabs

[image]

I want to make a tab host in such a way that if I swipe left inside the tab host, a new tab will appear from the right and pushes the rest towards the left. I want the new tab that would appear will be able to position itself properly. I want smooth transition effect in swiping, so can anyone give me idea on how to achieve this effect? any sample codes? or any useful links containing tutorials? I googled this up and sadly no result showing what I want.

One way that I could think of is applying a scroll view there that could only be scrolled horizontally. But one problem I am worrying is the automatic positioning of the item. How can I achieve that?

Please help. Many Thanks!

Comment: Try `ViewPager`, it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are looking for **ViewPager** and **PagTabStrip Example**.
google out on both topic and you will definitely find your ans.

Comment: Thanks man. Now I know its called "pager tab strip", and because of that I found a good source.